# Could the filter used on the home page be remembered?

Tags: feature-request, homepage, question-lists

Currently, if I go to https://stackoverflow.com/, what I get for the different question list options are by default `filter: recommended`, `show: all` and `sort: recently active`

When the page was redesigned I was happy that now, instead of [having to add every tag that I'm not interested in to my tag blacklist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FrQR.png), I could finally browse a list of only the questions I'd like to see and to which I could more likely provide an answer to.

My happiness ended as I noticed that switching `filter` to `favorite tags` appended a nice query string to the URL. This is nearly the same issue as YouTube making their "what to watch" the default page instead of your Subscriptions, what the site *thinks* you'd want to see, over the thing you willingly say you'd want to see.

With an *ENORMOUS* list of blocked tags, I can keep the home page mostly clean of other questions than my favourites, but some [still manage to pop up occasionally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8v5t.png), and over time I'd end up blocking a really large amount of tags, unnecessarily.

Could the site at least remember the `filter` option, if not everything?

While it'd be a fair argument to say that I could just make a user script that runs on every SO page and adds the query string to every link to the home page, I wanted to ask here first for a direct solution to the issue before attempting a work-around.